# Google Map и ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как сделать чтобы вместо или внутри этого div'a, отобразилась карта от гугла 
Возможно ли вообще такое?

```
.createElement('div',{className:'qwerty'}),_react2['default']
```

Comment: А какое отношение код в вопросе имеет к вопросу? Это раз. Два, есть же библиотеки, в которых есть реакт-компонент с гуглкартой. Пробовали их?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
// es6
import React, {Component} from "react";
class gMap extends Component {
    // вызовется один раз после инициализации
    componentDidMount() {
        // Создаем google карту.
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        // Здесь обновляем ее
        // newProps - ссылка на новые свойства, 
        // передаваемые компоненту.
        // Не вызывается при инициализации.
    }
    render() {
        <div id="g-map"></div>
    }
}
```